# How to write a code in selenium webdriver for a login page for the link mentioned below

Tags: selenium, authentication, webdriver

```
<a class="login" data-toggle="modal" href="/login/">Log in</a>
```

The code shown above is for clicking on a log in icon.
This is for a log in page for a website.
I am unable to write the code to click on the login icon.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://scratchkart.com/')

el = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Login')]")
el.click();
```

Comment: This could be added in comments

Comment: sorry, but my Reputation just 41

Comment: Its for the website http://www.scratchkart.com. At the top right corner there is a LOGIN/REGISTER icon. please click on it.

Comment: #!/usr/bin/env python

from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://scratchkart.com/')

el = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Login')]")
el.click();

Answer (score 0):

write something like this:

```
  WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Log in')]"));

 //Click on login
  element.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can login as follows:

```
elem=driver.find_element_by_id('email')
elem.send_keys('email@email.com')
elem=driver.find_element_by_id('password')
elem.send_keys('some_password')
elem.submit()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use selenium IDE to record your login action you can export it from the IDE in the language you want and the Selenium code will be written for you.